# Micro Focus Reflection SFTP.exe unable to connect issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, reflections

Currently having an issue in SQL Server Agent batch jobs running the Reflections SFTP.exe command. Upon execution we are continually receiving the unable to connect to host Ext code 43.

The account running the batch job has the permissions defined in this KB [https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7021931 to](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7021931%C2%A0to) no success.

There are no visible errors in Windows Event logs. We can get the job to work when the service account running the job is placed in an administrative group but we would prefer to not keep that account in an administrative group.

The job also seems to work in a pre-production environment with a non-administrator account.

Does anyone have any input on permissions or anything that could get this SFTP.exe job to work in SQL Server Agent without admin permissions?

Comment: Have you configured Windows Firewall to allow outbound connections on the port(s) you're using? Consider also modern alternatives to ancient COM-based software, e.g.: WinSCP has a .NET-based assembly that could be driven from your own software, including from SQL CLR procedures (if you need to keep things in-SQL, but it really should be an external process).

Comment: Firewalls are configured to allow outbound connections and there is no blocking happening on either end of the transaction. (outbound and inbound) Unfortunately for WinSCP it's not "approved software" for me to use on these servers.